# MongoDB query slow on very large collection - retrieve distinct documents based on field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having some problems making my MongoDB queries more efficient. My documents have the following format:

```
{
  _id: UUID,
  p: 'some.path',
  t: 'Fri Dec 12 2014 09:26:18 GMT+0100 (CET)',
  v: 123.4
}
```

where path and timestamp are indexed. The path is an identifier in our system, where we have around 15-16000 different paths. Our logging application is logging these values at around 3000 documents each second, and this is running fine without problems.

My problem is when retrieving a "snapshot in time" of these values; I want to make a query to know what all the signals are, at a given time. That means for each path, get the latest value where the timestamp is less or equal to the requested timestamp, and return all of these documents.

So in SQL/pseudocode:

```
results = []
for each distinct path:
  find document where p == path and t <= timestamp, order by t desc, limit 1
    results.push(result)
```

I have also gotten the same results by using aggregate with match, sort and group:

```
aggregate(
[
    { $match: { t : { $lte: timestamp}} },
    { $sort: { t : -1 } },
    { $group:
    {
    _id: { x: "$p"},
    p: { $last: "$p"},
    t: { $last: "$t"},
    v: { $last: "$v"}
    }
    }
]
```

However, with my collection currently clocking in at around 250 million records, both of these methods are very slow. I am really stuck on this, and can't seem to get this to work. If I cannot find a solution to this problem I will probably have to start looking at other databases that might support these types of queries better.

Comment: the date object your are displaying doesn't look like the mongo built-in type. Apart from that, I think you should restrict the $math-clause on both sides to have to group over a smaller sample (if still the query provided the right answers)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @fricke. You are correct in that the date format is not right, I just copied something from a terminal into the question as an illustration, and this is not the problem. As you suggested, I have tried limiting the $match clause to only an hour before the requested timestamp, and the query is faster, but still takes about 20 seconds to complete.

Comment: I guess this comes from the sheer amount of data you're having; optimising a groupBy is not easy and it's difficult to avoid a full scan of the data-set (the one the matches the match-clause) - oh and could you do me a favour a vote up my comment

Comment: I think the approach with the aggregation pipeline is the best one available for the current document structure. What are your performance expectations? How fast should the query be?